# Github Wiki's table and header

Tags: github, markdown, wiki, textile

What's the easy way to type wiki document in Github with header and table? Here is what annoying to me:

1. If I use **Markdown**, I have to use `<table>`.
2. If I use **Textile**, there is no `#` or `##` for header

I like the `|col1|col2|` syntax though.

What people use for this scenario? Without lots of typing / cut and paste (for `<table>` as example).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As
[can be seen](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/wiki),
it is surely possible.

```
dog | bird | cat
----|------|----
foo | foo  | foo
bar | bar  | bar
baz | baz  | baz
```

(this is using GitHub's "Markdown" Edit mode)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to force a particular alignment of the cells, you can do the following, where I have left-justified the first column, centered the middle column, and right-justified the last column:

```
dog | bird | cat
:-- | :--: | --:
foo | foo  | foo
bar | bar  | bar
baz | baz  | baz
```