# Render table in showoff

Tags: markdown, redcarpet

I'm using `showoff` for presentations with the default rendering engine (which I believe is `redcarpet`).

However, tables such as the following are not rendered:

```
<!SLIDE>
# Augeas releases

+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+    
| 1.0.0  | dec 2012 | Debian unstable, Ubuntu raring (and Augeas PPA), RedHat 5 (EPEL) |    
| 0.10.0 | dec 2011 | Debian wheezy, Ubuntu precise/quantal                            |    
| 0.9.0  | jul 2011 | RedHat 6                                                         |    
| 0.8.1  | apr 2011 |                                                                  |    
| 0.8.0  | feb 2011 |                                                                  |    
| 0.7.4  | nov 2010 |                                                                  |    
| 0.7.3  | aug 2010 |                                                                  |    
| 0.7.2  | jun 2010 | Debian squeeze                                                   |    
| 0.7.1  | apr 2010 |                                                                  |    
| 0.7.0  | jan 2010 | Ubuntu lucid                                                     |    
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Table should be
[arranged like so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268739/github-wikis-table-and-hea)

```
dog | bird | cat
----|------|----
foo | foo  | foo
bar | bar  | bar
baz | baz  | baz
```